# Set variable name in loop in Robot framework

Tags: loops, variables, robotframework

Broken with following task:
i want to set the name of variable in loop, like:

```
for i in 10:
    ${i}line = some value
```

How this can be done in Robot framework and if this is possible?
Thank you.
P.S. Sorry for dummy questions =\

Comment: Is this in a keyword, or in a variable file?

Answer (score 6):

**FOR / IN Scenario:**

FOR/IN statement is used as a loop for items in f.e. lists. The example below has these steps:

```
@{list}=    Create List    Var1    Var2    Var3
${index}    Evaluate    1
${line}    Set Variable    line
:FOR    ${i}    IN    @{list}
        Set Test Variable    ${${index}${line}}    ${i}
        ${index}    Evaluate    ${index}+1
```

1. Create list with some variables
2. Run loop through the list
3. Set dynamic test variable by catenating the ${index} value with ${line} string. This test variable holds the ${i} value looped from @{list}.
4. Evaluate index value by 1

**Results:**

```
${1line} = Var1
${2line} = Var2
${3line} = Var3
```

**FOR / IN RANGE Scenario:**

However, we can use range loop if the scenario requires running loop for certain number of times.

```
${line}    Set Variable    line
:FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    10
        Set Test Variable    ${${i}${line}}    ${i}
```

${i} variable is raised by one each time we use loop until the range 10 is reached.

**Results:**

```
${1line} = 1
${2line} = 2
....
${10line} = 10
```